# Determining the value of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac{1}{m^{mn}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2^{2n}}+\frac{1}{3^{3n}}+\frac{1}{4^{4n}}+\cdots\right) \tag{$\star$}$$

I have a strong suspicion that the above summation converges, although I'm not sure how to prove it. But I'm more interested in the precise value of $(\star)$, especially a nice representation (if possible).

Here's what I have so far:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2^{2n}}+\frac{1}{3^{3n}}+\frac{1}{4^{4n}}+\cdots\right) & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2n}}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3^{3n}}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4^{4n}}+\cdots \\ & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(2^{2}\right)^n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(3^{3}\right)^n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(4^{4}\right)^n}+\cdots \\ & = \frac{1}{2^2-1}+\frac{1}{3^3-1}+\frac{1}{4^4-1}+\cdots\\ & =\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n-1} 
\end{align}

So $(\star)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n-1}$. From here, all I know how to do is get an approximate value of the solution. How would you go about finding its exact value?

---

[image: Wolfram Alpha Summation Calculator]

Comment: I think you have already proved that the series converges, as it is true without any doubt for $\sum\frac1{n^n-1}$.

Comment: With what accuracy do you need to find the sum (*)? Easy to see that $(*) \approx \frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: Proving convergence is easy: $n^n-1>2^n$ for $n>1$.

Comment: Is there some way of proving whether an exact representational form exists or does not exist without actually finding such a form?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "an exact representational form"? You may introduce a function: $\Phi(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^n-1}$. Then the value of your series will be $\phi\equiv\Phi(1)$. Is it satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

If you want more figures $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n-1}=0.37605925334160927467565605197313357724916639675$$ All the digits are obtained summing up to $31$.

An amazing approximation of it is
$$\frac{76 \pi ^2+651 \pi-563 }{308 \pi ^2+481 \pi+1385}$$ which is in a relative error of $2.56\times 10^{-18}\text{ %}$.

**Edit**

Using exact arithmetic, I computed the value for $1000$ exact decimal places (if you want the number, tell me). The result is obtained summing up to $n=386$.

Whet looked interesting (at least to me) is that, negelcting the $-1$ in denominator
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n^n}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{e n}-\frac{1}{2 e n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ So, writing
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n-1}=\sum_{n=2}^{k-1} \frac{1}{n^n-1}+\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n-1}=\sum_{n=2}^{k-1} \frac{1}{n^n-1}+e^{\frac{1}{2 e}}I_0\left(\frac{1}{2 e}\right)\frac{ k }{k^k-1}$$
So, if we want the remainder to be less than $\epsilon$ we need
$$k\sim\frac{\log \left(\frac{b}{\epsilon }\right)}{W\left(\log \left(\frac{b}{\epsilon}\right)\right)}\qquad \text{where} \qquad b=e^{\frac{1}{2 e}}I_0\left(\frac{1}{2 e}\right)$$ Applied to the case where $\epsilon =10^{-1000}$, this gives $k=386.55$.

Comment: Hi Claude. I am not impressed by this approximation (just like by the well known rational approximations of $\pi$), sorry. Because it requires $18$ digits to achieve an approximation correct to $20$ digits.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Me neither ! Just amazed. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici A very interesting approximation indeed! Unfortunately it’s not exact but I nevertheless appreciate your stimulating contribution to this discussion. Thank you :)

Comment: @C.Melton. You are very welcome ! Inverse symbolic calculators do not find anything for this number. Cheers.